# (First time programming) How do you check an array of a class for a specific value?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have to design a simple banking program for school and I'm having trouble checking my array for a specific account number.

Base info, not the full code:

```
public class Account {

    public String name;
    int number;
    double Balance; 

    private Account [] accounts; 


    public Account[] getAccounts() {


        return accounts; 
    }

    public boolean hasAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {

       // How do I check my array of type Account if it has the passed in account number?
       // I was trying to use the following:

        Account[] b = getAccounts();
        if(Arrays.asList(b).contains(accountNumber)){
           return true;
        } else{
          return false;
        }

    }    
}
```

why isn't this working?

Comment: Why convert to list? Why not use list? Any reason you not using list?

Comment: What is the error, or the stacktrace showing?

Comment: How can you compare `Account` objects with integers?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to loop through the `Account`s and query each one for its account number.

```
boolean accountsContain(int accountNumber) {
  for (Account account : getAccounts())
    if (account.number == accountNumber)
      return true;

  return false;
}
```

(Side note: if it seems like there should be an easier way, there totally is, but Java can't do it (yet).  Look into Functional Programming)

Answer (score 1):

This is not returning the results because your original array consisted of objects and your code is checking of one of the objects is equal to the account number. This is not a valid comparison as what you should really be doing is to check if each object within the list has a number that equals account number.

So your algorithms will be,

```
1. Set current_position = 0; Start iterating through the list; 
2. Extract object at current_position
3. Does object.number == account_number? true {then break} : false {increment current_position}
4. Continue until end of array
```

Answer (score 1):

The array `b` contains `Account` objects, not numbers. So you'll have to manually iterate the array and check if each `Account` object matches that number:

```
public boolean hasAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
    for (Account account : getAccounts()) {
        if (account.number == accountNumber) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Having said that, a better design would probably be to store the accounts in a `Map` from the account number to the `Account` object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Because the elements of the array `b` are Objects while `accountNumber` is an **int** (primitive).
You have to iterate through the array `b` and compare the `number` instance variable of every object present in the array to the `accountNumber`.

Example:

```
public boolean hasAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
for (Account a : getAccounts()) {
    if (a.number == accountNumber) { 
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}